# Length of representation of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ in functions on Grassmannian

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Let $G=GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ be the (finite) group of all linear invertible transformations of the vector space $(\mathbb{F}_q)^n$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$.

$G$ acts naturally on the Grassmannian $Gr_{k,n}$ of $k$-dimensional linear subspaces of $(\mathbb{F}_q)^n$.

**What is the length of the corresponding representation of $G$ in the space of complex valued functions on $Gr_{k,n}$?**

Comment: What is the "length" of a representation? I have never heard that terminology before...

Comment: In this case length is equal to the number of irreducible components.

Comment: @SamHopkins "Length" is the length of the longest chain of subreps $0 = V_0 \subsetneq V_1 \subsetneq V_2 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq V_{\ell} = V$. In situations where all representations are direct sums of simple representations, it is the number of simple summands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that this is answered in Proposition 5.1 of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.08675) paper, which says that it is $\text{min}(k,n-k) + 1$.

Comment: In general, if a finite group $G$ acts on a finite set $X$, with $\mathbb{C} X = \bigoplus V_i^{\oplus c_i}$ being the decomposition into irreducibles, then $\sum c_i^2$ is the number of orbits of $G$ on $X \times X$. It is easy to see that there are $1+\min(k,n-k)$ orbits of $GL_n$ on $G(k,n)$ -- given $U$ and $V$ in  $G(k,n)$, look at $\dim (U \cap V)$. You want to compute $\sum c_i$, not $\sum c_i^2$, but it is very often true that all the $c_i$ are $0$ or $1$, and that is what happens here.

Comment: In this case we can be more explicit about the factors inductively.   There is a natural map $\mathbb{C}Gr_{k-1,n} \to \mathbb{C}Gr_{k,n}$ sending a $k-1$ dimensional subspace to the sum of all $k$ dimensional subspaces containing it.   If $n>2k$ this map is an injection, and the quotient is a unique new irreducible.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: That's a really clean way of seeing this.  Thanks!  I happened to have this paper at the back of my mind because it also shows how to deal with infinite fields.